# Find the eigenvalue of the non-diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have the next question:

> Suppose that $1$ and $2$ are eigenvalues of a linear map $\phi:\mathbb{C}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^3$. Moreover, suppose that $\phi$
>   is not diagonalizable. Let $p=p(x)$ denote the characteristic
>   polynomial of $\phi$. What can be $p(x)$?

As far as I understand, if the matrix cannot be diagonalized, this means that there is no basis that consist of eigenvectors. But what does that tell me about the third eigenvalue? That it is $0$? Or that the third eigenvalue can be as equal to $1$ as equal to $2$? Give me some hints plz

Comment: Hint: what happens if all eigenvalues are distinct?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth then the matrix will be diagonalizable?

Comment: Correct! So if the map is **not** diagonalisable, then...

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth but what about the $0$ eigenvalue?

Comment: If 0 is an eigenvalue as well then, 0, 1 and 2 are three distinct eigenvalues : therefore $\phi$ would be diagonalisable.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth But the zero vector in always linear dependent from another vectors, and we cannot make the basis with him, where matrix will diagonalizable.... where I am incorrect in my logic?

Comment: @Just do it Why are you concerned about the zero vector? Note that by definition an eigenvector is a non-zero vector.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thx, my mistake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third eigen value is $1$ or $2$. Hence $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^{2}$ or $p(x)=(x-2)(x-1)^{2}$.